# How to enable Wi-Fi in HP ProBook 455G?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, lts

As in title, after changing operating system from 12.04 lts I can't connect to Wi-Fi, Ethernet connection works. It doesn't shows anything about Wi-Fi like disconnected. In software & updates I found out actually my additional driver is X Org. X Server.

Answer (score 0):

The first think you should do is install the Ubuntu [LTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).  Your X.org drivers are for you graphics display and will have nothing to do with your networking drivers.

The EnablementStack may just solve your problem, because it will give you access to newer supported Linux kernels on the LTS versions of Ubuntu.

I am guessing your notebook is an HP Probook 455G1, but could you post your exact part number?

From the HP support site for the HP Probook 455G1, it looks like you have either the a Realtek or Broadcom wireless adapter.  Realtek support is generally pretty good, but Broadcom is less so.

[HP Quickspecs (Realtek & Ralink)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)
[HP Drivers (Realtek & Broadcom)](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=5359416&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=2020)

[Ubuntu Ralink](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ubuntu%20Ralink)
[Ubuntu Realtek](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ubuntu%20realtek%20wireless%20drivers)
[Ubuntu Broadcom](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ubuntu%20realtek%20wireless%20drivers)

You can find more information about your hardware using `lspci`